# Is setting this reference thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I keep getting mixed answers as to whether this code is thread-safe or not. I am working in Java 8.

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
private volatile Object reference = null;

public Object getOrCompute(Supplier<Object> supplier) {
    if (reference == null) {
        synchronised(lock) {
            if (reference == null) {
                reference = supplier.get();
            }
        }
    }

    return reference;
}
```

My expectation is that given a new instance of this class, multiple calls to `getOrCompute()` will only ever result in one supplier being called and the result of that supplier being the result of all calls (and future calls) to `getOrCompute()`.

Comment: According to [this article](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) by some pretty heavy Java names your code is thread safe thanks to the `volatile` reference.

Comment: I'm hoping `supplier.get()` can never return `null`.

Comment: @AndyBrown What's the problem if it returns null

Comment: @grape_mao It will be called on every invocation of `getOrCompute()`.

Comment: @grape_mao. That depends on whether or not it consistently returns `null`, or sometimes returns `null` and sometimes an `Object`. I'm *really* hoping it isn't the latter.

Comment: @biziclop sorry, I didn't see op's expectation...

Comment: It would be good to hear the arguments that you have heard for why this code is not thread safe.

Comment: things to consider when invoking alien code `supplier.get` - if it returns null, throws exception, or causes recursion, i.e. it calls getOrCompute

Answer (score 3):

It is safe because whatever is done in `supplier.get()` must not be reordered with the assignment to `reference`. (Or to be more precise, it mustn't appear to be reordered when you do a volatile read of `reference`.)

The lock provides exclusivity and the volatile write/read semantics provide visibility. Note that this has only been true since Java 5, which was released a long-long time ago, but you'll still find outdated articles on the Internet about how double-checked locking (for that's the official name of this idiom) isn't working. They were right at the time but they are obsolete now.

What can be unsafe though is the supplier itself, if it supplies a mutable object. But that's a different matter.

Comment: the mutability of the reference is irrelevant for the threadsafety of the assignment..

Comment: @Vogel612 I didn't imply that it was (see the first three words of my answer :)). It's an aside.

Comment: Or at least I didn't **mean** to imply it. I may have done so accidentally :)

Comment: Even though volatile is synchronous nowadays, it still doesn't stop threads from accessing it in various orders. It's not thread safe, it's multi-access safe.

Comment: @Gemtastic For a write-once field like this the two are equivalent.

Comment: @ChrisK Without the volatile keyword there are no guarantees that you'll see a fully constructed object on subsequent reads. (Unless the object only has `final` fields.)

Comment: For all we know, someone might in an other part of the code turn the `reference` variable into null again, and that's not thread safe. The variable is accessible after all.

Comment: @ChrisK No, the synchronized keyword only guarantees visibility for those who also synchronize on the same lock. But you want to avoid that.

Comment: @Gemtastic The variable is private and it's safe to assume that OP included all the relevant code in the post.

Comment: No, it's **not** safe just because the provided code doesn't have what can break it, if other code can, in the future it might and therefore it is not safe.

Comment: @Gemtastic The question was whether **this** code was safe. Not whether it will stay safe if some hypothetical code is added to it in the future. Of course it won't stay safe if you set the value of `reference` more than once but that will be a different code.

Comment: @biziclop And the answer is that any thread in any order can access this method, but only the first one can instantiate the object at a time. This is not thread safe, but it's multi-access safe. Only one thread can instantiate it.

Comment: @Gemtastic Okay, let's approach this from a different angle. Does the order in which `getOrCompute()` is invoked by different threads affect the output? The answer to that is no, not unless `supplier.get()` has a side-effect, which it shouldn't have. That means the method is **idempotent**. And idempotent units of code are thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization is not thread safe. It's hindering the threads from accessing the object all at once, but it has no control over which thread gets it when or what it does with the object once it's gained access to it. Synchronization only limits access to one thread at the time, the thread that access it first get to access it first.

In this case, the only thing it does is preventing several threads to instantiate the object. If the object already is instantiated, it will be handed out to whatever thread wants it with no thread safety what so ever.

Imagine you have one thread accessing the method and instantiating the object, it retrieves it and while it's retrieving the object, another thread is trying to instantiate it, which it won't be allowed to since it exist so it can jump straight to retrieving the object, just like thread number one, these can now modify the object at the same time, ergo, not thread safe. But the instantiation of a new object is thread safe in the manner that the object can only be instantiated once.

Comment: `In this case, the only thing it does is preventing several threads to instantiate the object.` It does far more than that, it ensures visibility of the supplied object to all subsequent callers. Which is the definition of "safe".

Comment: Yes, I bulked what it does inside of the synchronised block as "instantialization" because when you push it to its edge, that's what it does; it replaces the value/reference of `reference` with whatever is in `supplier.get()` so that part IS thread safe; only one thread can do that. But the `reference` object is not thread-safe and can be altered however the threads receiving it wants to.

Comment: The OP's example illustrates a well known design pattern, _double checked locking_.  The entire point of double-checked locking is to initialize a singleton object in a thread-safe way.  So if the only thing it does is prevent several threads from instantiating and using different instances of the class, then it does exactly what it is supposed to do, and it does it in a thread-safe way.